# Need answer about some Machine Learning related questions?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

Recently, we planned to build a system for image processing to extract info from images. At present we are using `AWS` Rekognition to do that. But, in some cases, we are not getting accurate information from AWS. So, we've planned to build our own custom one.

We've 4/5 months to do that. At least a `POC` version. Also, we've planned to use `Tensorflow` for that. We all have no prior experience about Machine Learning & Deep Learning but already have 5/6yrs of experience on Computer Programming by using different languages.

Currently, I'm studying ML from a course of `Udemy` & my approach to solve this problem is...

- Learn Machine Learning(ML)
- Learn Deep Learning(DL)
- Above ML & DL maybe I'll be ready to understand the whole thing & can able to build a system for Image Processing.

In abstract what I've understood is, I've to write one Deep Learning program in `Python` by using `Tensorflow`. By using that Program I've to build a Model. Then I've to train that Model by using some training data. Then, when my Model achieves a certain level of accuracy I'll use some test data.

Now, there some places at where I've bit confused & here are my questions regarding that confusion...

1. I know `tensorflow` is a library but at some places, it's also mentioned as a system. So, is it really a library(piece of code) only & something more than that?
2. I got some Image Processing Python code in `Tensorflow` tutorial section (https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/image_recognition). We've tested that code & it's working exactly the way `AWS` Recognition service work. So, here my doubt is... can I use this Python code as it is in our production work?
3. After train a model with some training data does those training data get part of the whole system or Machine Learning Model extract some META info from those training data & keep with itself rather whole raw training data(in my case it'll be raw images).
4. Can I do all these ML+DL programmings over my Linux System? It has Pentium 4 with 8GB RAM.
5. Also, want to know... the approach which I've mentioned to build a solution for my problem is sufficient or I need to do something else also.

Need some guidance to clear out all these confusion.

Thanks

Comment: what sort of image recognition task you want to do? is it classification?

Comment: In a basic sense, it'll be like AWS Rekognition - https://aws.amazon.com/rekognition/ where System will scan images & return different stuff found in images as a response with a confidence score. But on that, we've some plan to customize it according to our bussiness need.

Comment: No my question is like, is one image contains multiple objects, or one image contains only one object. Let's say there is an image which contains dog and cat, so you want to predict region of object along with type of object or image contains only dog or only cat and you want to predict its type(cat or dog).

Comment: It's can be both. But, mostly it's like one image with multiple things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 : `tensor-flow` is like anything else we have been worked with (like `Numpy` ) but only difference is we have to first defined what we want to use the use it , every thing in `tensor-flow` are running into a computational graph and evaluating every thing in that graph require a Session , we could call it library because it just piece of code and have interface in python , and system because of all those mechanism it uses

2 :
`can I use this Python code as it is in our production work?` Why not !

3:
yes you could do that with your system , but the main advantage of tensor-flow and theano , .. the tool like those is that you could run your code on GPU it a more faster way than on CPU because the GPU could handle a lot more matrix multiplication and stuff like that

4:
you know you don't have to learn all the machine learning stuff to built a image recognition system , it may be take years for you to understand whats going on there , `Udemy` course is very good source but you I highly recommend you to see the machine learning courses of `coursera` , there is to courses there about machine learning : the great `Andrew NG` course and `Emily fox` course , the first one is more theoretical than practical , but second on is more practical ,
and about the Deep learning , there is nothing fancy about Deep learning and it's just a method in machine learning , after you gain some experience in machine learning and understood some basic or you could do it right know , go to `fast.ai` , it has a really good course about deep learning for coder and it's also free

I hope this will help you

Comment: Thanks for this information. Here are some follow-up questions... is TensorBoard is a part of Tensorflow or it's a separate tool? What's in my mind is - Maybe in some way TensorBoard is a part of TensorFlow & that's why it's called a System.

Comment: Second, about that Python code... If that 's free to use then why someone will use the paid version Google Vision API or AWS Recognition API?  Actually, I can't able to fig. out what's exactly the difference between both of them.

Comment: About learning ML/DL - Before starting ML I've tried to go through directly to Deep Learning but at some point, I feel I need to know those basics of ML. That's why I'm currently studying ML. These are two courses I'm currently using for that - https://www.udemy.com/machinelearning/  & 
https://www.udemy.com/deeplearning/

Comment: One more doubt, how deep learning model store information after having trained with some training data. Is it store whole training data in its system or stores some meta-information only in its system or nothing like this happen? Sorry for asking so much doubt.

Comment: @mi6crazyheart I'm sorry bro, I have some exprience with pure tensor flow  but I'm not tensorflow expert  but I could give you this hint , in deep learning area after your deseignig architecture is done you dont implement it with pute tensor , there are tools out there that could make this simpler for you like keras , that could have theano and tensor-flow at back end

Comment: @mi6crazyheart about your second Q : yes the tool is free , but some times(and in practical and industrial work almost every time ) when you want to train your network on huge data set , if you wanted to run on your cpu or regualar GPU of your system it could take week or mounth or even a year :D , so the Amazon offer you AWS that you could run your project on their system to make it easier and faster for you , see the first tutorial of fast.ai about AWS

Comment: @mi6crazyheart it's OK bro , we could kind of say it store meta information , but you know it's have a whole theory behind it that I cant explain here , you could look at this book diagram to figure this out : http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/